# Repeating text in file - problems with a loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I want my programme to read some stuff from a file, but add new elements to my list only if the element appeared for the 1st time. My problem is that I don't know how to check it. The loop would look like this:

```
file >> someData >> someData2;
if(someData appeared for the 1st time)                
            {
                add someData to list;
            }
else
            add someData2 to list2;
```

I know how to do everything inside the loops, but the condition inside `if` is problematic, since the programme doesn't remember previously read data.

My ideas are: checking every element of the list or using a temporary tab which would store someData and would disappear after the function ends.

Comment: A `std::set` would make this problem trivial. If the item is not in your set it is the first time. Are you prohibited to use the standard library?

Comment: _someData appeared for the 1st time_ is true when the data is not in _list_. As it was said one of the best way to do that efficiently is to use a _std::set_ for list, except if the order is relevant for you, in that case you can use a std::list for _list_ but the search will be more expensive

Comment: *but the search will be more expensive* Much MUCH more expensive. Unless you have a good reason, prefer `std::vector` to `std::list`.

Comment: @user4581301 yes, but the add is more expensive for a std::vector rather than for a std::list when the internal allocated size is too small and it is needed to copy it in a new one. Anyway an other advantage of the std::vector is the memory size. Of course you know that userxx, that remarks are for Lilo :)

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use the standard library and have to use lists (without std::list, just a structure with elements and pointers).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as pointed out in the comments, the STL approach would be to use 'std::set'; For the sake of thoroughness, I will illustrate how to use both std::set, and how to use plain C;

### C++

```
// initial 'list' setup
std::set<decltype(someData)> listA;
std::vector<decltype(someData2)> listB;

// filling in data
file >> someData >> someData2;

// Insert the data into the set
// if the value already exists, leave it alone and push an element into listB
if(!listA.insert(someData).second) listB.push_back(someData2);
```

### C

```
// some dynamically allocated arrays
char * listA;
unsigned listAsize;
char * listB;
unsigned listBsize;

// data variables (chars, for simplicity)
char dataA;
char dataB;

// loop variable
unsigned i;

// read data
readMyData(&dataA, &dataB);

// insert conditionally into lists
for(i = 0; i < listAsize; ++i) {
  if(list[i] == dataA) {
     // insert dataB into list B
     break;
  }
}

if(i == listAsize) {
  // insert dataA into listA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Standard library containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). They do almost all of the work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream file("A B1 C D1 A B2 C D2"); // fake input file in memory

    std::string someData; // assuming strings because they are easy
    std::string someData2;

    std::set<std::string> list1; 
    std::vector<std::string> list2;

    while (file >> someData >> someData2) // read in inputs until end or failure
                                          // note: Not handling failures
    {
        auto result = list1.insert(someData); // attempt to add to list1
        if(! result.second) // if already in set
        {
            list2.push_back(someData2); // add to list2
        }
    }

    // print contents of lists
    for (const auto & out: list1)
    {
        std::cout << out << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto & out: list2)
    {
        std::cout << out << ' ';
    }
}
```

[Documentation for `std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

[Documentation for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

[Documentation for `std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)